# Make all rows same height as first one css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using

.grid {
grid-template-rows: max-content max-content;
}

But the second row is too short (because the content is less tall than in the first row).

Instead of this I want the first row to be as tall as its content, and the second row to be exactly the same height as that row was made. So, `1fr 1fr` doesn't work nor does `max-content 1fr` (because those use available space rather than fitting content).

How can I make the first row have `max-content` height and the second row have the same height as the first one?

Comment: I think you need JavaScript for this. As far as I know Elements can't inherit height from siblings.

Comment: `1fr 1fr` should work, share your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're right

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the **grid-auto-rows** property?

as in:

```
grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
```